# Undefined Reference In OpenCV3

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-14.04, opencv3.0

Following the suggestion from [Install OpenCV and compile C program using GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676018/install-opencv-and-compile-c-program-using-gcc),

I still get the following error messages from the command "gcc `pkg-config --cflags opencv` FrameExtractor.c `pkg-config --libs opencv` -o fe"

[image]

Here is the simplified source code, which have the same error message

```
#include <opencv/cv.h>
#include <opencv/highgui.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    CvCapture* videoFileCapture = cvCreateFileCapture( argv[1] );
    if( NULL == videoFileCapture )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    cvReleaseCapture( &videoFileCapture );
    return 0;
}
```

System:
Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

OpenCV:
3.1.0

pkg-config --cflags opencv:
[image]

pkg-config --libs opencv:
[image]

Please let me know if any suggestion and thank you for taking time on my question.

Comment: I have opencv 3.1.0 installed on my computer and my `pkg-config --libs opencv` is completely different: `-L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab`. Could you try `pkg-config --modversion opencv` o check if the version of pkg-config is the right one (`3.1.0`)?

Comment: Hello francics, Thank you for the quick response. I confirmed that 3.1.0 is installed in my machine by pkg-config --modversion opencv. The difference between your and mine are 1. the order 2. lopencv_viz. Do you think the order will affect the linkage? Please let me know if any other suggestion. Thanks, again!!!